# RegEx- Check if its a masked number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex that will check for a valid mask. The mask can contain as many * as it would like but it has to be followed by only 4 numbers.
For example I would like these to pass:

```
********1234
******1234
```

and these to fail:

```
********123
********12345
******12*34
******1234*
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^\*+\d{4}$
```

or, if you're stuck in a language without `\d`

```
^\*+[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\*+\d{4}$/
```

This pattern will look for an entire string that starts with one or more asterisk (`\*+`), followed by exactly four digits (`\d{4}`, which could also be expressed as `[0-9]{4}`).